# Error downloading 'BouncyCastle.1.8.6.1' from api.nuget.org

Tags: jenkins, nuget

Environment: Jenkins 2.249.1 on Windows Server 2016.

The command being used is

```sh
nuget.exe install itextsharp.pdfa -PreRelease -Version 5.5.13.2 \
    -OutputDirectory C:/Jenkins/workspace/itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop/src/extras/packages \
    -Source 'C:/Jenkins/workspace/itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop/;https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
```

This is the relevant part of the console log:

```
02:17:42  Feeds used:
02:17:42    C:\Jenkins\workspace\itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop\src\extras\global-packages
02:17:42    C:/Jenkins/workspace/itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop/
02:17:42    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
02:17:42  
02:17:42  
02:17:42  
02:17:42  Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'itextsharp.pdfa.5.5.13.2' with respect to project 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop\src\extras\packages', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
02:17:43  Gathering dependency information took 215.09 ms
02:17:43  Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'itextsharp.pdfa.5.5.13.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
02:17:43  Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
02:17:43  Resolving actions to install package 'itextsharp.pdfa.5.5.13.2'
02:17:43  Resolved actions to install package 'itextsharp.pdfa.5.5.13.2'
02:17:43  Retrieving package 'BouncyCastle 1.8.6.1' from 'nuget.org'.
02:17:43  Retrieving package 'iTextSharp 5.5.13.2' from 'C:/Jenkins/workspace/itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop/'.
02:17:43  Retrieving package 'itextsharp.pdfa 5.5.13.2' from 'C:/Jenkins/workspace/itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop/'.
02:17:43    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg
02:17:43    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg 165ms
02:17:43  WARNING: Error downloading 'BouncyCastle.1.8.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
02:17:43  Could not find file 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop\src\extras\global-packages\bouncycastle\1.8.6.1\bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
02:17:43    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg
02:17:43    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg 24ms
02:17:43  WARNING: Error downloading 'BouncyCastle.1.8.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
02:17:43  Could not find file 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop\src\extras\global-packages\bouncycastle\1.8.6.1\bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
02:17:43    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg
02:17:43    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg 23ms
02:17:43  WARNING: Install failed. Rolling back...
02:17:43  Executing nuget actions took 482.72 ms
02:17:43  Error downloading 'BouncyCastle.1.8.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
02:17:43    Could not find file 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\itext_7_dotnet_pdfxfa_develop\src\extras\global-packages\bouncycastle\1.8.6.1\bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg'.
```

It looks as if `nuget install` is making 3 attempts to GET `bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg`, it *appears* as if that works, and I have also verified that https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bouncycastle/1.8.6.1/bouncycastle.1.8.6.1.nupkg is a valid URL: when you open this link, a nupkg file will download. But then for some unknown reason, the download doesn't work?

**Already tried**

When I remove the BouncyCastle directory from `packages` and `global-packages`, and then run the job a second time, the download of BouncyCastle by `nuget install` succeeds.

When I then run the job a third time, without clearing out the directories again, it fails again on the same error.

What do I need to do to make the `nuget install` command complete successfully in all circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a root cause and it's taking too much time so I have taken a pragmatic approach.
I will now now always delete BouncyCastle at the start of the build, like this:

```
sh 'rm --force --recursive ${dest}/global-packages/bouncycastle'
```

It's dirty and I'm not proud of it, but it works.